# location.reload event triggers the button click events

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a simple requirement. Need to refresh a parent page from child window once it closes. I am opening a child window from a button click event like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showPage", "javascript:showPage();", true);
```

and javascript method in parent page is

```
function showPage() {
        window.open("Page2.aspx", "Shan", "width=200,height=200,scrollbars=no");
    }
```

and in child page i have

```
function refreshAndClose() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        self.close();

        //window.opener.location.href = "Default.aspx"
        //self.close();
    }
```

and calling this in

`<body onunload="refreshAndClose();">`

Now its working as expected it calls the page load event of parent window when I close the child window but its also going intto the button click event (the button click event through which i called the child window) and executes the javascript method again. So again Child window appears and this goes recursively.

How to avoid this ? I am nbew to asp.net. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showPage", "javascript:showPage();", true);
            }
        }

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myWindow;
        function showPage() {
            myWindow = window.open("Page2.aspx", "Shan", "width=200,height=200,scrollbars=no");

            setInterval(function () {
                alert("ap");
                if (!myWindow) {
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has never been opened!";
                } else {
                    if (myWindow.closed) {
                        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has been closed!";
                        form1.submit();
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has not been closed!";
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="msg"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```